# Keep state of navigation controller and only change view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have an application with a drop down menu as the `titleView` of my `NavigationController`. When a user selects an item of the drop down menu, the entire view should switch contents, however, the `NavigationBar` should remain the same. The NavigationBar **should not have to reload any data** and the titleView should **remain a drop down menu**.

The original view upon opening the app:

[image: Original View]

The view upon touching the dropdown menu:

[image: Drop Down Menu]

I currently see a few ways of going about this:

1. **Set up a `UIViewController` for each option, perform the segue, and reload the data.**

   - *Why this is bad:* I will have to set up a segue identifier for each `ViewController`, meaning if I have 15 options in my drop down menu, I will have 210 segue identifiers laying around. I will also have to reload all of my `NavigationBar` data.
   - *Why this is good:* I will have a clear area to set up each individual view.
2. **Programmatically add and remove `UIButtons`, `UILabels`, and `UIWhatevers` as I need them.**

   - *Why this is bad:* This will create a lot of code inside just one `ViewController` and things could get difficult to debug.
   - *Why this is good:* The `NavigationBar` never gets reloaded.
3. **Add a container and embed a unique `ViewController` for each item as I need it.**

   - *Why this is bad:* All of my work would still be in the main `ViewController` and I'd have to manage the logic of the embedded `ViewController` inside one Controller.
   - *Why this is good:* The `NavigationBar` never gets reloaded.
4. **A completely different method suggested by someone else because I don't know the most efficient way of doing this.**

So, in conclusion, what is the most efficient way to maintain state of my `NavigationBar` when switching my main content in my `View`?

Comment: Is this UINavigationController the root view of your application? (Basically a UITabBarController that has a drop down menu at the top instead of a UITabBar at the bottom)

Comment: Yes the NavigationController is the root view.

Comment: Option 3.  I don't see why it would get complicated.  The root view controller would just be responsible for switching out the view controllers in the container view.  Each of the contained view controllers would still be self contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 is the best out of the three you listed. Options 1 and 2 will get more and more complicated the more view controllers you want to add. Compare that to `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController`, or `UIPageViewController` which do not need to be more complicated in order to handle 10 screens vs. 100 screens.

I would suggest creating a custom container view controller ([Apple's Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)))

I see 2 immediate approaches to implementing this:

1. Subclassing `UIViewController` - this is how Apple's container view controllers are implemented
2. Subclass `UITabBarController` - I have done this successfully, subclassing `UITabBarController` to show a custom tab bar at the top instead of along the bottom.